# issue in sending mails in bulk in php

Tags: php, ajax, email

I am design a form for sending mail in bulk via phpMailer, for example i want to send a mail to 50 persons.but the issue is after sending mail 10 to 15 persons my form gives an file not found exception.

my ajax call is given below

```
.on('success.form.bv', function(e) {            
        e.preventDefault();     
        $('#send_email_next').modal({
                backdrop: 'static'
            });
        $.ajax({ 
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "email_next.php",
                        data: $("#emailform").serialize(),
                        success: function(html){ $("#modal_body").html(html);}
        });
    });
```

Phpmailer function called in email_next.php is given below

```
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
require_once("class.smtp.php"); 
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$body=" ";
set_time_limit(0);
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Timeout       =   10000;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->do_debug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                       // set the SMTP port
$mail->Username   = $account_user_name;     // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = $password;            // GMAIL password
$mail->From       = $account_user_name;
$mail->FromName   = 'Rayat Bahra Group';
$mail->Subject    = $_POST['subject'];   
$mail->AltBody    = ''; 
$mail->WordWrap   = 50; 
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->MsgHTML($content);
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$SN = 0;
$error_mail=0;
$total_mails_to_send = count($email_array);
foreach($email_array as $recipient_address)
{
$mail2 = clone $mail;
$mail2->MsgHTML($content);
$mail2->AddAddress(trim($recipient_address));
$status = $mail2->Send();
if($status)
{
    $SN++;
}
else{
    $error_mail = 1;
}
echo $SN." out of ".$total_mails_to_send. " sent <br>";
}
if($error_mail == 1)
    {
        echo "Message was not sent <br />PHPMailer Error: " .  $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
else{

    echo "Message has been sent";
}
$mail->SmtpClose();
```